# Array em PHP para JSON

Tags: php, json

Olá,, tudo bem?

Estou pegando os valores de uma tabela em um banco de dados e "transformá-los" em JSON. Estou com o seguinte código PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pessoas";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

$arr = array();

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $arr['nome'] = $dados['nome'];
    $arr['sobrenome'] = $dados['sobrenome'];
}

return json_encode($arr);
```

Porém, ele me retorna apenas

```
{"nome":"Leo","sobrenome":"Nerone"}
```

Mas gostaria que ele retornasse tudo, por exemplo:

```
{"nome":"Leo","sobrenome":"Nerone"},
{"nome":"Alguem","sobrenome":"Loco"}
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está criando um array apenas com o último item, pois o loop sobrescreve o item gravado anteriormente.

Crie um `$arr` multidimensional:

```
while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $arr[] = array( 'nome' => $dados['nome'] , 'sobrenome' => $dados['sobrenome'] );
}
```

sua saida será um array como:

```
$arr[0] = array( 'nome' => 'Leo' , 'sobrenome' => 'Nerone' )
$arr[1] = array( 'nome' => 'Alguem' , 'sobrenome' => 'Loco' )
```

Comment: +1 Essa é a melhor solução e resolve o problema.

Answer (score 3):

Tente isso:

```php
$return_arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $row_array['nome'] = $row['nome'];
    $row_array['sobrenome'] = $row['sobrenome'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Com `array_push($return_arr,$row_array);` você estará empilhando, a cada iteração, o resultado da consulta consulta, na variável `$return_arr`, criada antes do laço.

Comment: poderia comentar e explicar o codigo por favor? assim quem fez a pergunta podera entenderr o que voce respondeu. Voce pode [edit] a sua resposta.